# in a nested map find key and update its value

Tags: recursion, elixir, updates, key-value, nested-map

> find key `: sum` in `nested map` and update its value to `: bill * 100 + : coins`

**Need to pass test1**

```elixir
test "test1" do
  assert BcToInt.data(%{
            count: 3,
            sum: %{bills: 1, coins: 99},
            tax: %{count: 3, sum: %{bills: 1, coins: 1}}
          }) ==
            %{count: 3, sum: 199, tax: %{count: 3, sum: 101}}
end
```

I tried to do it using `Map_replace()` and  checking value for nested map using `is_map` and call function again if `true` but how to get end result

```elixir
def data(xmap) do
  Enum.map(xmap, fn {_key, value} ->
    keyy = :sum

    aa = List.first(Map.values(xmap[keyy])) * 100 + List.last(Map.values(xmap[keyy]))

    if Map.has_key?(xmap, keyy) do
      Map.replace(xmap, keyy, aa)

      if is_map(value) do
        data1(value)
      end
    end
  end)
end
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the test case – the `sum` line has `bill` and not `bills`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version without using external libraries:

```elixir
def data(map) do
  map =
    case map[:sum] do
      %{bills: bills, coins: coins} -> %{map | sum: bills * 100 + coins}
      _ -> map
    end

  Map.new(map, fn
    {k, v} when is_map(v) -> {k, data(v)}
    entry -> entry
  end)
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> data = ...
%{
  count: 3,
  sum: %{bills: 1, coins: 99},
  tax: %{count: 3, sum: %{bills: 1, coins: 1}}
}
iex(2)> BcToInt.data(data)
%{count: 3, sum: 199, tax: %{count: 3, sum: 101}}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a help of `iteraptor` library:

```elixir
Mix.install([:iteraptor])
Iteraptor.map(data, fn
    {_k, %{bills: bills, coins: coins}} -> bills * 100 + coins
    # Is not `bill:` a typo?
    {_k, %{bill: bills, coins: coins}} -> bills * 100 + coins
    other -> other
  end, yield: :all)

#⇒ %{count: 3, sum: 199, tax: %{count: 3, sum: 101}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation correctly uses recursion to look into nested data structures.  It looks like it's trying to use `Map.replace/3` to try to modify the data structure in place, though.  Elixir only has immutable data structures, so you need to construct a new map from the input rather than trying to update it in place.

I might implement the recursion here using pattern matching:

```elixir
def data(%{bills: bills, coins: coins}) do
  bills * 100 + coins
end

def data(map) when is_map(map) do
  Map.new(map, fn {k, v} -> {k, data(v)} end)
end

def data(any) do
  any
end
```

With this setup, if `data/1` is called with a map with the `:bills` and `:coins` keys (not necessarily in a field named `:sum`) it adds them together; on any other map, it recurses through the values preserving the keys; and on any other value it returns the original value as-is.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def data(xmap) do

   keyy = :sum

   aa = List.first(Map.values(xmap[keyy])) * 100 + 
        List.last(Map.values(xmap[keyy]))

   
     Map.new(xmap, fn
       {k, _v} when k == keyy -> {k, aa}
       {k, v} when is_map(v) -> {k, data(v)}
       {k, v} -> {k, v}
     end)
  

  end
```

Comment: You should not rely on the order of the values in a map, because they are considered to be unsorted. Instead, look up the values you need by their key.